# #Value Error on Query - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to combine the data in two sheets into another sheet by using the below code:

```
=UNIQUE(ArrayFormula(query({filter('Sheet1'!A2:B,NOT(ISBLANK('Sheet1'!A2:A)));filter('Sheet2'!A2:B,NOT(ISBLANK('Sheet2'!A2:A)))},"order by Col1")))
```

It works perfect if both sheets have at least 1 row filled but if either of the tabs are empty, then I receive #Value.

How can I fix this code so that it still works if either of the tabs are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter throws an error instead of returning no values, a property that is very annoying in this case.
Since you're already using the query command why don't you try this, either one or both ranges can be completely empty.

```
=UNIQUE(ArrayFormula(query(
  {Sheet1!A2:B; Sheet2!A2:B},
  "WHERE Col1 is not null order by Col1")))
```

Alternatively if Col1 contains always strings a shorthand is `Col1 <> ''`

Comment: Hey Robin, thanks for the reply! I have tried the solution and started to receive this error instead: "Query completed with an empty output."

Comment: Changing condition as "WHERE Col1 is not null" worked but this time it's not combining two sheets, it's just returning the first sheet :/

Comment: OK I figured it out :) "WHERE Col1 is not null" modification works, thanks very much!

Comment: You are right, my where clause only works is the whole column contains strings. I'll amend that.